# Update Row in datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have a jquery script in which i have a datatable but when i would like to edit a field in datatable it does not show me that the field is modify knowing that in the database the field is modify but i would like to display in row the field that already modify.

In the method addPost i used this code is it works very well.

addPost :

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID </th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Body</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach($post as $key => $value)
                <tr class="post{{ $value->id_post }}">
                    <td>{{ $value->id_post }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->body }}</td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
             @endforeach

           </tbody>
    </table> 

$("#add").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "{{action('PostController@addPost')}}",
              data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'title': $('input[name=title]').val(),
                'body': $('input[name=body]').val()
              },
              success: function(data){

                  $('.error').remove();
                  $('#example').DataTable().row.add([
                  "<tr class='post" + data.id_post + "'>"+
                          "<td>" + data.id_post + "</td>",
                          "<td>" + data.title + "</td>",
                          "<td>" + data.body + "</td>",
                  "</tr>"]).draw();

              },
        });
```

But in the method editPodt it does not work.
i tried with this code but also it does not work :

editPost :

```
$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.edit', function(){

        var tableRow = $('#example').row($(this).parents('tr'));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{action('PostController@editPost')}}",
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'id_post': $('#id_post').val(),
                'title': $('#title').val(),
                'body': $('#body').val()
            },
            success:function(data){

            var rData = [
                "<td>" + data.id_post + "</td>",
                 "<td>" + data.title + "</td>",
                 "<td>" + data.body + "</td>",
                        ];
            $('#example')
                .row( tableRow )
                .data(rData)
                .draw();

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your datatable initialization code?

Comment: @Sagar , it's done I post my datatable code, but in my method editPost doesn't work

Comment: In editPost you have missed `$('#example').DataTable()`

Comment: [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) returns the array of ancestors. So you should be getting element at first index like `var tableRow = $('#example').row($(this).parents('tr').get(0));` And according to [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) you don't need to pass html `tr` `td` tags.